# Terraform variable validation

Tags: validation, variables, terraform

How to use loop or something else to make it efficient way not using regex.

```
variable "instance_auto_renew_period" {
  description = "Instance auto-renewal period (in months). Set it to 0 if you want to disable auto renew of DB instance."
  default     = 0
  type        = string
  validation {
    condition     = contains(["0", 1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"], var.instance_auto_renew_period)
    error_message = "Must be an valid instance_auto_renew_period."
  } 
}
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Do you have examples of valid input and invalid ones?

Comment: valid input is between [0-12] if any value more than 12 is not acceptable
want to achieve same thing as posted in above snippet, but with loop or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to achieve that is as follows:

```
variable "instance_auto_renew_period" {
  description = "Instance auto-renewal period (in months). Set it to 0 if you want to disable auto renew of DB instance."
  default     = 0
  type        = number
  validation {
    condition     = var.instance_auto_renew_period <= 12 && var.instance_auto_renew_period >= 0
    error_message = "Must be an valid instance_auto_renew_period."
  } 
}
```